# Rs232 software flow control

Tags: windows, serial-port, hardware, flow-control

I have a general question about Rs232 Software Flowcontrol (aka XOn/XOff)

The .Net implementation (and the nativ win32 api) bothe define a property called WriteTimeout / ReadTimeout, which is a time in ms after which a communication is considered to be overdue.

No my problem is this: If I send, lets say a 5 Byte string to the device I don't see any WriteTimeout, as expected. How is this implemented? Everything I find about Software flow control is that XOFF is to be set, when the recieve buffer is full; XOn when it is ready to recieve again.

But from the behavior I see, I would suspect, hat the device sends XON, after it has processed the 5-Byte information that I send, thus creating the information for windows to generate the corresponding events.

So when to send XON on a two-wire only RS232 implementation? Only if the buffer was full and to restart recieving; Or to signal, that we are "still ready" to receive after every chunk we processed?

How to implement?

Cheers & thx in advance!

Corelgott

Comment: What are you implementing exactly? Are you writing software or designing hardware?

Answer (score 0):

Send an `XON` any time you are ready to receive data (your receive buffer is empty or nearly so). Send an `XOFF` any time you cannot accept more incoming data (your receive buffer is full or nearly so). The process is documented on the Wikipedia [software flow control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_flow_control#Mechanism) page.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the wiki. "But: The other end receives the XOFF code, and suspends transmission. Once the first end is ready to accept data again, it sends XON, and the other end resumes transmission." In this context, XON should only be send if XOFF was send? OR: Send XON every time the controller has processed any data? Host sends "abcdef"; Client responds with XON; Host sends "ghijk"; Client responds with XON?

Comment: You don't need to send an `XON` unless you previously throttled the other end. You might, however, want to send an `XON` periodically to protect against noise being interpreted as an `XOFF` and stalling communication.

Answer (score 0):

From said [Wiki reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_flow_control#Mechanism), these are messages sent by the receiving party on a serial link -

```
XOFF - Pause transmission
 XON - Resume transmission

"When one end of a data link ('Receiver') is unable to accept any more
data it sends XOFF to the other end. The other end ('Sender') receives 
that XOFF code and suspends transmission. Once the first end ('Receiver')
is ready to accept data again it sends XON, and the other end ('Sender')
resumes transmission"
```

So for your example, you send XON to the device when your receive buffer has available room and you are ready to receive bytes on this channel